# How to use the SQLite.NET designer Visual Studio add-in

Tags: visual-studio, database-design, add-in, system.data.sqlite

I've installed SQLite.NET and during the installation I checked the boxes about design-time support, which should be a Visual Studio add-in I can use to model databases.

However, I can't seem to find out how to open/start this designer. Could anyone post a simple instruction please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this add-on equals the feature described on http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/:
"Visual Studio 2005/2008 Design-Time Support
You can add a SQLite connection to the Server Explorer, create queries with the query designer, drag-and-drop tables onto a Typed DataSet and more! SQLite's designer works on full editions of Visual Studio 2005/2008, including VS2005 Express Editions.
* NEW You can create/edit views, tables, indexes, foreign keys, constraints and triggers interactively within the Visual Studio Server Explorer!"
I think it's just about the ability to use the common database-related features of VS with SQLite.